# Solve for $\alpha$, $z^* ( B^* + \alpha A^* )^{-1} A ( B + \alpha A )^{-1} z = c$, where ${\rm rank}(A)=1$,$B$ full rank matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis

> **Problem**:
>
> Let $A \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$ be a rank one matrix, $B \in M_{n,n} (\mathbb{C})$ be a full rank matrix, $z \in M_{n,1} (\mathbb{C})$ be a column vector, and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ are given, then
>
> Solve for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ (which is non-negative, i.e., $\alpha > 0$) such that 
>   \begin{align}
> z^* \left( B^* + \alpha A^* \right)^{-1} A \ \left( B + \alpha A \right)^{-1} z = c \ .
> \end{align}
>
> Is it possible to obtain a closed-form solution for $\alpha$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think a solution exists? Here are some examples where no solution exists (or infinitely many exist without $z=0$).

Let $A=\pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0}$, $B=\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$. Then $(B+\alpha A)^{-1}=B-\alpha A=\pmatrix{1 & -\alpha \\ 0 & 1}$ and $(B^*+\alpha A^*)^{-1}=\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ -\alpha & 1}$. It follows that $(B^*+\alpha A^*)^{-1} A (B+\alpha A)^{-1} = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & -\alpha}\pmatrix{1 & -\alpha \\ 0 & 1}=\pmatrix{0 & 1\\ 0 & -\alpha}$. Setting $z=\pmatrix{z_1\\z_2}$, we have 
$$c=z^* B^*+\alpha A^*)^{-1} A (B+\alpha A)^{-1} z = \pmatrix{z_1^* & z_2^*}\pmatrix{z_2 \\ -\alpha z_2} = z_1^*z_2-\alpha |z_2|^2. 
$$
If $z_2\neq 0$ and $z_1^*z_2$ is real, you get the solution $\alpha = \frac{z_1^*z_2-c}{|z_2|^2}$. This number is not always positive. If $z_1^*z_2$ is not real, there is no real solution. If $z_2=0$ and $c=0$, any $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ solves the equation. If $z_2=0$ and $c\neq 0$, no solution exists.

Comment: You have a point, thanks. Now if I add constraints that $B$ and $A$ are hermitian, then what do you say?

Comment: Just to mention that I have raised another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907787/solve-for-alpha-z-b-alpha-a-1-a-b-alpha-a-1-z-c-w, and we keep this question.