# Solve for $\alpha$, $z^* ( B + \alpha A )^{-1} A ( B + \alpha A )^{-1} z = c$, where ${\rm rank}(A)=1$,$B$ full rank matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis

> **Problem** (I raised a [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907652/solve-for-alpha-z-b-alpha-a-1-a-b-alpha-a-1-z-c), **but** in this problem $A$ and $B$ are additionally Hermitian):
>
> Let $A \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$ be a rank one matrix *and Hermitian*, $B \in M_{n,n} (\mathbb{C})$ be a full rank matrix *and Hermitian*, $z \in M_{n,1} (\mathbb{C})$ be a column vector, and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ are given, then
>
> Solve for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ (which is non-negative, i.e., $\alpha > 0$) such that 
>   \begin{align}
> z^* \left( B^* + \alpha A^* \right)^{-1} A \ \left( B + \alpha A \right)^{-1} z &= c \\
> z^* \left( B + \alpha A \right)^{-1} A \ \left( B + \alpha A \right)^{-1} z &= c \ \hspace{5mm} \textrm{since } A \textrm{ and } B \textrm{ are Hermitian}. 
> \end{align}
>
> Is it possible to obtain a closed-form solution for $\alpha$?

NOTE:

- If $B = I$ and $A$ is Hermitian then one can solve the problem in closed form. However, I don't know yet how to solve for any Hermitian matrix $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is rank one and Hermitian, then we can write
\begin{equation}
 A = aa^H
\end{equation}
So the equation is now

\begin{align}
z^H \left( B^H + \alpha A^H \right)^{-1} aa^H \ \left( B + \alpha A \right)^{-1} z =c
\end{align}
which is 
\begin{equation}
 \vert a^H(B + \alpha A)^{-1}z \vert^2 = c
\end{equation}
Let's solve 
\begin{equation}
 a^H(B + \alpha A)^{-1}z = \sqrt{c}e^{i \theta} = d
\end{equation}
for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. This means in your solution, you will have a free $\theta$ parameter.
Now, let's apply the [Matrix Inversion Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) and since $B$ is invertible, we can say:
\begin{equation}
 (B + \alpha aa^H)^{-1}
 =
 B^{-1} - \alpha \frac{B^{-1}AB^{-1}}{1 + \alpha a^H B^{-1} a}
\end{equation}
Plugging this we get
\begin{equation}
 a^H(B^{-1} - \alpha \frac{B^{-1}AB^{-1}}{1 + \alpha a^H B^{-1} a})z =  d
\end{equation}
which is 
\begin{equation}
 a^H B^{-1} z 
 -
 \alpha \frac{a^HB^{-1}AB^{-1}z}{1 + \alpha a^H B^{-1} a}
 =
  d
\end{equation}
which is 
\begin{equation}
 [a^H B^{-1} z][1 + \alpha a^H B^{-1} a] - \alpha[a^HB^{-1}AB^{-1}z]
 =
  d[1 + \alpha a^H B^{-1} a]
\end{equation}
Let 
\begin{align}
 \beta_1 &= a^H B^{-1} z \\
 \beta_2 &= a^H B^{-1} a\\
 \beta_3 &= a^HB^{-1}AB^{-1}z = \beta_2\beta_1
\end{align}
Rearranging, we get
$$\alpha=\frac{\beta_1 - d}{d\beta_2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, Ahmad! It is indeed very neat. I have one question for now (perhaps more when I think more about it): would this free parameter $\theta$ not have the impact, although $\alpha $ root should be (non-negative) real valued? I will ponder over this more. Again, thank you for the good start.

Comment: One clarification. How did you get 
\begin{equation}
 a^H B^{-1} z 
 -
 \alpha \frac{a^HB^{-1}AB^{-1}z}{1 + \alpha^2 a^H B^{-1} a}
 =
  d
\end{equation}

Comment: Should it not be ?\begin{equation}
 a^H B^{-1} z 
 -
 \alpha \frac{a^HB^{-1}AB^{-1}z}{1 + \alpha a^H B^{-1} a}
 =
  d
\end{equation}

Comment: So sorry about that, i think you"re right, looks like you got an easier problem now

Comment: I have edited .. please double check

Comment: Thank you, it looks good.